# Make IIS server max_file_upload size 10GB

Tags: iis, files, upload

I am working on a website that is hosted with the company's own server, using IIS. I was wondering if it's possible to make the make file upload size 10GB? Their assets they send and receive to clients are generally between 5GB to 10GB.

Just wondering what changes are necessary to achieve this (changing upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit). I am going to try to raise the limit tomorrow.

Best,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the maxAllowedContentLength setting in your web.config file to set the upload limit per website. This can also be done using the GUI by going to request filtering and setting it there.

Comment: Hi Vikrant, I did try both ways via IIS and the web.config file. In the end, I was unable to increase it over the limit of 2 GB. I also tried increasing the max_upload_size in the PHP .ini file but again no luck.

After speaking with the client, they said that they were fine with the 2  GB max, so I left it as is.